# container_memory_working_set_bytes giving more value

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus

I am using Prometheus for Kubernetes cluster monitoring.
In grafana for memory usage, I am using

```
    sum(container_memory_working_set_bytes{namespace=~"$Namespace"})  by (container)
Result is
    {container="tagging"}   7112409088
```

This is giving me incorrect. When I am using the command for individual container

```
container_memory_working_set_bytes{container="tagging"}
Result is
container_memory_working_set_bytes{container="tagging",...} 3575762944
container_memory_working_set_bytes{container="tagging",...} 3536646144
```

this is giving me different result

What is the issue here? Am I missing here something? I am assuming this is doing across all pods(2 in this case). Basically I need two data points

```
a) Memory usage by per pod
b) Memory usage by container(avg by pod)
```

Comment: You’re receiving different values because you're summing the values of the containers in the first query, but in the second one you're obtaining the values for each one. But if you sum those values, it will give the same result as the first query. Please provide more information about the issue. Did you already review the official documentation about Grafana and Prometheus?